# php replace last character of specific character

Tags: php, arrays, join, replace

I have an array and I want to generate a message out of them.
If I use `join(', ', $response)`, I get `file1.jpg, file2.jpg, file3.jpg`. Is it possible to replace the last comma so the message would be `file1.jpg, file2.jpg AND file3.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work;

```
<?php 

$response=['file1.jpg','file2.jpg','file3.jpg'];

$response=array_reverse($response);

$arr=$response[1].' AND ' .$response[0];
for ($i=2; $i < count($response); $i++) { 
    $new[]=$response[$i];
}
array_push($new, $arr);

echo join(", ",$new);
```

Comment: Thats great, can you mark the answer as the right one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_slice` to get all the elements in the array but the last one and make a special case for it :

```
function formatList($response)
{
    if(count($response) == 0)
        return '' ;
    if(count($response) == 1)
        return $response[0] ;
    else
        return join(', ', array_slice($response, 0, count($response)-1)) . ' AND ' . end($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`substr_replace` replace a portion of a string by position and length, `strrpos` find position of the last comma.

```
$response = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.jpg'];
$out = join(', ', $response);
echo substr_replace($out, " AND", strrpos(($out), ','), 1);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php